# Play video on image mouseover causes trempling glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, onhover

I am trying to play video while hovering over images at the same div in my website's img-gallery but obviously i am doing something wrong.

The supposingly hidden image over which the video should play on mouseover starts trempling. 
I think its something obvious but i don't have enough experience to solve it.

Is there any idea how to hide the image at hovering for good?

Here is the code:

HTML

```
        <div id="container">
     <div class="viewer">
       <img class="thumb" target="#video_1" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-76jgnJ-JmHU/VBZvGw5LDWI/AAAAAAAAAGs/C0yoeoqoouU/s1600/golesengif.png">
       <video id="video_1" preload loop>
         <source src="https://fat.gfycat.com/ShockingDependableHogget.webm" type="video/webm">
         No video support
       </video>
       </div>
     <div class="viewer">
       <img class="thumb" target="#video_2" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-76jgnJ-JmHU/VBZvGw5LDWI/AAAAAAAAAGs/C0yoeoqoouU/s1600/golesengif.png">
       <video id="video_2" preload loop>
         <source src="https://fat.gfycat.com/ShockingDependableHogget.webm" type="video/webm">
         No video support
       </video>
       </div>
     <div class="viewer">
       <img class="thumb" target="#video_3" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-76jgnJ-JmHU/VBZvGw5LDWI/AAAAAAAAAGs/C0yoeoqoouU/s1600/golesengif.png">
       <video id="video_3" preload loop>
         <source src="https://fat.gfycat.com/ShockingDependableHogget.webm" type="video/webm">
         No video support
       </video>
       </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    .viewer {
    width: 530px;
    height: 290px;
    display:inline-block;
    }

    video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
    }
```

JS

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.thumb')
        .mouseover(function() {
          $(this).hide();
          var myVid = $(this).attr('target');
          $( myVid ).show().trigger('play');
       })
       .mouseout(function() {
          $('video').trigger('pause').hide()
          $(this).show();
      });
    });
```

Here is also a saved [PEN]:https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEwRJQ

Comment: The issue is because you hide the `.thumb` in the mouseover, so the mouseout is immediately called which shows it again. This is why it flickers. What behaviour are you expecting exactly?

Comment: thanx for the immediate answer!  i would like to play videos on my images while hovering and then on mouse out , leave the image as it were. i dont care if the video is paused or stopped after mouse out.

Comment: Got it. I added an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your code is because you're hiding the `.thumb` element in the `mouseover` event which immediately triggers the `mouseout` event which shows it again. This causes a loop of hiding/showing which results in the flickering you see.

To fix this, hook the event to a parent element of both the thumb and the video. That way you don't need to use the non-standard `target` attribute and can instead find the related `video` element using DOM traversal, making the code more extensible and robust. You can also use the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to prevent any possible flickering when near the edges of the hit area.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.viewer').mouseenter(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.find('.thumb').hide();
    $el.find('video').show()[0].play();
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    $el.find('.thumb').show();
    $el.find('video').hide()[0].pause();
  });
});
```

```css
.viewer {
  width: 530px;
  height: 290px;
  display: inline-block;
}

video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div class="viewer">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-76jgnJ-JmHU/VBZvGw5LDWI/AAAAAAAAAGs/C0yoeoqoouU/s1600/golesengif.png">
    <video id="video_1" preload loop>
     <source src="https://fat.gfycat.com/ShockingDependableHogget.webm" type="video/webm">
     No video support
   </video>
  </div>
  <div class="viewer">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-76jgnJ-JmHU/VBZvGw5LDWI/AAAAAAAAAGs/C0yoeoqoouU/s1600/golesengif.png">
    <video id="video_2" preload loop>
     <source src="https://fat.gfycat.com/ShockingDependableHogget.webm" type="video/webm">
     No video support
   </video>
  </div>
  <div class="viewer">
    <img class="thumb" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-76jgnJ-JmHU/VBZvGw5LDWI/AAAAAAAAAGs/C0yoeoqoouU/s1600/golesengif.png">
    <video id="video_3" preload loop>
     <source src="https://fat.gfycat.com/ShockingDependableHogget.webm" type="video/webm">
     No video support
   </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your quick and  in-depth solution , it was also food for thought, keep up!

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.viewer').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.mouseover(function() {
      $(this).find('.thumb').hide();
      $('video', $this).show().trigger('play');
    })
    $this.mouseout(function() {
      $('video', $this).trigger('pause').hide()
      $(this).find('.thumb').show();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Remember we're here to educate people, not just dump code. A description of the problem and why your code helps will be a benefit to the OP and all future visitors.

Comment: Sure, seems Rory answered above anyway but just to clarify I believe you were triggering your events on '.thumb' and so your reference to $(this) gets confused, here im confining $this to an iteration of viewer. You can then do things like reference elements within $this --- $('video', $this).trigger()